# How can I show that $u(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have been struggling with this assignment that came up as my test question.

Suppose $u(x,y)$ is a real-valued harmonic function.

How can I show that $u(x,y)$ can be written in the form  $f(x + iy) + g(x - iy)$, with $f$ and $g$ holomorphic

Answer (score 1):

You know that $u$ is the real part of an holomorphic function $h$. Thus $$u(x,y) = \Re(h)(x+iy) = \frac{1}{2}h(x+iy) + \frac{1}{2}\overline{h}(x+iy).$$ Now set $$l(z) = \overline{h}(\overline{z}).$$ The function $l$ is clearly holomorphic (take the $\overline{\partial}_z$) and we have $$u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}h(x+iy) + \frac{1}{2}l(x-iy).$$ Now take $f = h/2$ and $g=l/2$ to get your statement.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I have edited my post.